# access a sails application outside of a localhost context

Tags: sails.js

Let generate a new Sails application and lift it:

```
> sails new foobar
> cd foobar
> sails lift
```

When I browse `http://localhost:1337`, I see in the chrome console the ascii boat and "`io.socket` connected successfully" and my template app is well displayed.
Now, if I try to browse the same URL in any browser of any other host of my network, using the IP of my dev computer (for instance `http://192.168.1.1:1337`), my app is well displayed but I don't have the "websocket connected" thing in the console.

What I miss?

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set `io.sails.url` in your frontend? Ive no problems using different hosts with 0.11rc5

Comment: No, but when I deploy my app on heroku, I encounter no problems with websockets. It only happends on my local networks, when I try to join my webserver from any other computer of my house. Maybe a problem with my local equipment...

Comment: Really strange. Open your browser dev-tools and take a close look to the network tab. Probably you get any hints here